# A related question to the Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

Suppose $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Then, Weierstrass Approximation Theorem asserts that there is a polynomial on $[a,b]$ which is as close to $f$ as we want (in a uniformly approximation sense).

It is my question :

Let $S$ be a set $\big\{ \big| \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} \big| : a \leq x < y \leq b \big\}$,
which is a set of absolute values of slopes between every two distinct points of $f$.

Then, is the set $S$ bounded above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on, for example, $[0,1]$.  The average rate of change of $f$ is unbounded for pairs of points near $0$.

Consider also
$$  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 - \sqrt{1-x^2} ,& 0 \leq x < 1  \\
    1 - \sqrt{1 - (x-2)^2} ,& 1 \leq x \leq 2
\end{cases}
$$
Its graph is two quarter circles meeting at a vertical tangent.
[image: Mathematica graphics]
The average rates of change are unbounded for sample points near (and on the same side of) $1$.

Answer (score 3):

No.

$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, let $[a,b]=[0,1]$. $f$ is continuous but $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $\exists x \in [0,1]$ such that $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \geqslant n$

Answer (score 1):

The set is unbounded for a generic continuous function $f$. Take for example $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$. If your set is bounded, your function is called Lipschitz continuous.